# How to get Associated Simple Product Id using Attribute Option Id of a Configurable Product Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

How to get Associated Simple Product Id using Attribute Option Id of a Configurable Product in Product View Page in Magento2? For Ex: A Configurable Product with Attribute Size and Options L,M,S. How to get Simple Product Id of L,M,S ?.

Comment: Did you found any solution for that ? I have same question

Comment: No solution yet....